# How to know a class's lowest base is some type

Tags: c#

For exmaple, have a type A, how can I know one of its ancester is Windows.Forms.Form?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "lowest ancester". The base of all the type hierarchy is Object so nothing can have a Form instead. If you mean the concrete type, Form is pretty rare an i can't see the usage...

Comment: A.BaseType == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form)

Comment: maybe A is derived from commonform, commonform is derived from Form

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) method on Type:

```
var myType = typeof(Form1);
var formType = typeof(Form);

Console.WriteLine(myType.IsSubclassOf(formType)); //outputs 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
var x = yourValue;
var t = x.GetType();
var p = t;
while (p.BaseType != null) 
{
  p = t.BaseType;
}
```

If you're looking for a specific type, rather than just wondering what the base is, you test for it.

```
var myX = x as WhateverType;
if (myX != null)
{
  // Use myX
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, it's "lowest ancestor" will always be the universal base class, `Object`. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one shortcut for checking for an ancestor relationship between types. That is, A is derived from Form if a variable of type Form can refer to A:

```
Type aType=typeof(A);

...
bool isFormAnAncestorOfA = typeof(Form).IsAssignableFrom(aType);
```